# How do I access urls present in a shape or a text run of a Presentation using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperlink, python-pptx

I am reading data from a pptx file using python. I need to access the hyperlinks/urls present in it.

```
    ppt2 = Presentation('../sample dataset/'+ file_name)
    for slide in ppt2.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
               click_action = shape.click_action
               if click_action.action == PP_ACTION.HYPERLINK:
                    print(click_action.hyperlink.address)
```

I have tried this and it did not work. it did not show any output.

I need the urls present in the hyperlinks as output. But i did not get any output.
[sample of how the ppt slide looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW2j8.png)

The hyperlink with text 'sample text' has a URL. I need to access the url (please see the ppt slide image).

Comment: _I have tried this and it did not work._ --> What does that mean? Did you get any errors (if so, please [edit] your question and add the complete error message)? Or just no output? Are you sure that those links are not images?

Comment: There is just no output. Yeah I am sure the links are not images

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for the clarification. So you are creating the pptx? Is it possible for you to add a sample pptx instead of that screenshot?

Comment: No I wasn't creating the pptx. I was accessing an already created pptx. I just created a sample slide because I didn't want to share the ppt I was working on.

Comment: @GaneshRajK,  Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if hasattr(shape, "hyperlink"):
            hyperlink = shape.hyperlink
            hyperlink_address = hyperlink.address
            hyperlink_text = ""
            if hasattr(shape, "text"):
                hyperlink_text = shape.text
            print("hyperlink_text", hyperlink_text, "hyperlink_address", hyperlink_address)
        elif shape.has_text_frame:
            for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                for run in paragraph.runs:
                    if not hasattr(run, "hyperlink"):
                        continue
                    hyperlink = run.hyperlink
                    hyperlink_text = ""
                    if hasattr(run, "text"):
                        hyperlink_text = run.text
                    hyperlink_address = hyperlink.address
                    if hyperlink_address == None:
                        continue
                    print("hyperlink_text", hyperlink_text, "hyperlink_address", hyperlink_address)
```